# Magento 2.4.6 Opimize database tables

Tags: database, magento2.4

I'm using Magento 2.4.6, I want optimize the database, Some tables have large entries.

```
report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly
report_viewed_product_index
```

What is the use of these tables?

Can I truncate these tables from live site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to truncate the **report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily, report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly, report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly, and report_viewed_product_index tables** in Magento 2. However, you should exercise caution when doing so, as truncating these tables will remove all historical data related to viewed products, and **you won't be able to recover the data**. You must take **backup of these tables** then you can start truncating on it.

**The purpose of these tables are given below :**

- **report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily:** This table stores aggregated data on the daily views of products. It contains
  pre-calculated data for various attributes like product IDs, store
  IDs, view counts, and timestamps. Aggregated data is stored on a
  daily basis, allowing you to see trends in product views over time.
- **report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly:** Just like the previous two tables, this one stores aggregated data as well, but on a yearly
  basis. It gives you an even broader perspective of product views over
  the course of a year.
- **report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly:** Similar to the daily table, this table stores aggregated data, but on a monthly basis. It
  provides a higher-level overview of product views for each month.
- **report_viewed_product_index:** This table contains the actual individual records of product views. It stores data on every view
  event, including details like customer ID, product ID, store ID, and
  timestamp. This table forms the basis for populating the aggregated
  tables mentioned above.
  Please let us know if you have any other query.